# Problem while taking user input via fmt.Scanln() in golang

Tags: go, input, buffer, user-input

I m trying to take an input from the user through my console in **golang** by using **fmt.Scanln()**. It is working fine under normal circumstances. However, whenever I take input in a loop, the inputs are correct in the first iteration but during the **next iterations** of a loop, an **extra smiley** is added in the front of the received string. I don't know what the problem is. Will be very thankful if anyone proposes some solution.

```
func (a *Block) fillBlock() {
fmt.Println("Block Details:")
fmt.Print("Enter Block Name: ")
fmt.Scanln(&a.Data)

for i := 0; i < Students; i++ {
    fmt.Print(i, "Enter Student Roll# ")
    fmt.Scanln(&a.Grades[i].Rollno)
    fmt.Print(i, "Enter Student Grade# ")
    fmt.Scanln(&a.Grades[i].Grade)
}

fmt.Println("\nInput Data:")

fmt.Println("Data: ",a.Data)

// Iterating over each student
for i := 0; i < Students && (a.Grades[i].Rollno != "" && a.Grades[i].Grade != ""); i++ {
    fmt.Println("Rollno: " + string(i) + a.Grades[i].Rollno)
    fmt.Println("Grade: " + string(i) + a.Grades[i].Grade)
}
```

}

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
    fmt.Println("Rollno: " + string(i) + a.Grades[i].Rollno)
```

Instead, use

```
    fmt.Println("Rollno: " + strconv.Itoa(i) + a.Grades[i].Rollno)
```

Or, better:

```
    fmt.Printf("Rollno: %d %s\n",i a.Grades[i].Rollno)
```